# Return vector of majority factor levels per n rows/observations in R

Tags: r, rows, mode

For example, I have a dataframe with two factor variables and 1000 rows. I would like to reduce the number of observations to 200 by returning vectors that give the most frequently occurring level for every 5 rows.

```
 df <- data.frame(test=factor(sample(c("A","B", "C" ),1000,replace=TRUE)))
 df$test2 <- factor(sample(c("dog", "cat", "fish"), 1000, replace=TRUE))
 head(df, 15)

     test test2
1     C  fish
2     B   dog
3     A  fish
4     B  fish
5     B   dog
6     A   cat
7     B   cat
8     C  fish
9     C  fish
10    C   cat
11    B   dog
12    A  fish
13    B   dog
14    B   cat
15    C   dog
```

I would like the output to give two columns as follows:

```
testANS      test2ANS
B            fish
C            cat
B            dog
```

I have found examples where the most common catagory is found across columns within a row but not down columns and by number of rows. Thanks in advance for any advice. Will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'test', 'test2' and a variable created by replicating the sequence of 200 by 5 ('grp'), grouped by 'grp', we get the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`) where the 'N' is maximum (`which.max(N)`).  If needed, we can assign the 'grp' and 'N' columns to 'NULL'.

```
library(data.table)
res <- setDT(df)[, .N, by = .(test, test2, grp = rep(1:200, each = 5))
             ][, .SD[which.max(N)], by = grp][, c("grp", "N") := NULL][]
dim(res)
#[1] 200   2
```

As the OP didn't use `set.seed` for creating the `sample`, the output will be not the same.  By using the first 15 rows showed in the OP's post

```
setnames(setDT(df1)[, .N, by = .(test, test2, grp= rep(1:3, each = 5))
   ][, .SD[which.max(N)] , grp][,  c("grp", "N") := NULL][], paste0(names(df1), "ANS"))[]
#    testANS test2ANS
#1:       B      dog
#2:       C     fish
#3:       B      dog
```

#### Update

Based on the comments, it seems that the column frequency should be done separately

```
setDT(df1)[,  grp:= rep(1:3, each = 5)][,
     testN := .N ,by = .(grp, test)][, test2N := .N, by = .(grp, test2)
       ][, .(testANS = test[which.max(testN)], test2ANS = test2[which.max(test2N)]), grp]
#   grp testANS  test2ANS
#1:   1       B      fish
#2:   2       C       cat
#3:   3       B       dog
```

NOTE: In the original dataset, change `rep(1:3, each = 5)` to `rep(1:200, each = 5)`

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(test = c("C", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "B", "C", 
"C", "C", "B", "A", "B", "B", "C"), test2 = c("fish", "dog", 
"fish", "fish", "dog", "cat", "cat", "fish", "fish", "cat", "dog", 
"fish", "dog", "cat", "dog")), .Names = c("test", "test2"),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

Comment: Hi akrun, thanks for the reply. Apologies for not using set.seed. I've run it a few times on the data and I'm finding that it is coping pretty well with the 'test' variable but is quite often bringing back the incorrect factor level for the 'test2' variable? This can be seen above too in the differences between the output when you ran it on the df1 and the example output I gave. Do you have any idea why this might be?

Comment: @Noosentin That was a mistake from my part.  I thought it is based on the whole frequency for the two columns instead of separate frequency.  I updated the post.  Please check it.

Comment: Thank you this works great and will be very helpful. Much appreciated!